# Oculus Unity error: Failed entitlement check: 1 - App running from non-trusted source

Tags: unity-game-engine, oculus

I just changed my Oculus account, and now I can not Initialize the Oculus Api.

```
// Ensure OvrPlatform is Initialized
if (OvrPlatformInit.status != OvrPlatformInitStatus.Succeeded)
{
    OvrPlatformInit.InitializeOvrPlatform();
}

while (OvrPlatformInit.status != OvrPlatformInitStatus.Succeeded)
{
    if (OvrPlatformInit.status == OvrPlatformInitStatus.Failed)
    {
        if (mouseCoordinates != null)
        {
            mouseCoordinates.MultiplayerError();
        }
        OvrAvatarLog.LogError($"Error initializing OvrPlatform. Falling back to local avatar", "");
        yield break;
    }

    yield return null;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to this problem.

To run inside Unity Engine I had to follow this requirements:

- Reedem an Oculus key for my App to have it on the Oculus Library.

To run a production build I had to follow this requirements:

- Reedem an Oculus key for my App to have it on the Oculus Library.
- Allow apps from Unknown Sources under in the Oculus App under Settings -> General.
- Add the Oculus Account as an organization member in the Oculus Developer Dashboard.